# Why won't my webGl page load a second time after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This is a JS page my friend and I are making.
http://jmecom.github.io/GameUniverse/

The page loads fine when you first open it in a tab (albeit a little slow), but when you refresh the tab, the WebGl canvas will just be completely blank. The HTML elements are displayed though. We're using Three.js. Are there browser compatibility issues with WebGL that could be related? Is something being cached and causing an issue?

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an SVG with a line in it. The problem is because your event listener fires before the SVG finishes loading up!

The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when the HTML tags load up in your document. `DOMContentLoaded` won't wait for the SVG to finish loading, though.

Instead of using `DOMContentLoaded` for your event listener, use `load`, which will fire once everything is loaded.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll test it asap when I get home. Do you know why this is only a problem after a refresh? Is DOMContentLoaded triggered faster because the DOM was already loaded once?

Comment: Yes, because Chrome loads from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering this bug in Chrome, but not Firefox, so I suspect it's due to your missing a semi-colon on line 692 of scripts.js, which Firefox is compensating for: [image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for catching that. I'll have to change that as soon as I get back on my home computer. Will update to see if that fixes things.